# Can I prevent the leaf loss from my fern?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, watering, soil, leaves

I’ve had this house Fern for around two months, and made every attempt to keep it healthy. It had been put in a slightly larger pot with pebbles at the bottom to help the water drain. I ensure the soil is moist at all times and water about once every two to three days. The first month it seemed fine but in the last week the leaves have started to fall, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?? [image: Fern][image: fern close up]

Answer (score 3):

The most common causes of decline in houseplants are not enough light and too much water.  Those seem possible here and the typical low humidity of interior areas could be a factor.

The pebbles that you mention could be problem too.  If they are inside the pot they should be removed as they contribute to a [perched water table](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13774/what-is-a-perched-water-table).

This best way to improve the health of this plant is:

- move to a higher light area.  Diffuse southern exposure  (no direct light but strong light through sheers or drapes) or strong northern or eastern sun
- try a different watering technique: take the pebbles out of the pot and put them in a deep tray underneath the pot.  Take a piece of fabric or polyester and insert part into the pot and trail the rest into the tray.  You now have a [wicking system](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/4002/499).  The plant draws as much water as needed and no more.  No change of root rot and as the water evaporates in the tray it will raise the humidity slightly