# Black spots peace lily

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, peace-lily

[image]

I have black spots on my peace lily and I don’t know what to do.. I did spray a homemade mixture of canola oil, Pine Sol and water because I was afraid there were some sort of lice or fungus on it. It is standing on the corner of a window and gets a lot of indirect sunlight. I water it 1 time per week and spray water on the leaves a few times per week.

Answer (score 2):

The black spots are typical of a fungus/virus/bacteria infection brought on by stress from overwatering or poor sanitation at the growers.  This looks like the very common [Cylindrocladium spathiphylli](https://negreenhouseupdate.info/photos/spathiphyllum-cylindrocladium-root-and-crown-rot) for which the symptoms [are described](http://mrec.ifas.ufl.edu/Foliage/Resrpts/rh_96_5.htm) as "dime size circular brown necrotic lesions form surrounded by yellow halos".

Remediation for growers is destroying the infected stock and treatment of the growing area with a fungicide not normally available to homeowners.

Good news is that you can treat this condition yourself:

- move to a higher light area
- do not allow the plant to sit in water
- change the plant to a pot in a pot system and add a wicking system as described [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/4002/499)

Most healthy plants can outgrow infections if they given better conditions.