# Date palm not growing

Tags: trees, palm

I planted my date palm 3yrs ago now. So far it has has grown 3 very long leaves, but no stem / trunk. These leaves have also grown tremendously slowly. The soil I have used it Miracle-Gro Indoor Potting soil. I water it once every 2 weeks or so. I just cannot figure out why it's not growing. My room is very sunny; but it is placed just out of direct sunlight.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't hurt to give this Middle East desert plant maximum sun gradually. You are allowing for about 5% of the sun it expects.

Answer (score 4):

is it a old desert say: "plant a date palm, so your sons will see the fruits from it"? So: it is a very very slow-growing plant.

My experience on a green house is similar (and a green house has sun from all directions): healthy (so many new shots/leaves), but slow. And I assume both of us doesn't live in desert so the ideal conditions of such plant, so add few extra decades.

Answer (score 1):

I am growing a date palm from seeds and it is five or six years old now and at least two meters tall. My observations:

- this plant needs full sun. To get good growth I put it outside in the summer when temperatures are above 10 degrees Celsius
- it is a vigorous grower when given full sunlight and unlimited access to water
- a vigorous root system indicates that repotting can be done yearly if light and water are supplied
- never had any pest problems
- thorns on the fronds are a safety issue
- works well with a [capillary wick system](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/4002/499)